# application resources not updated when clear app from memory and reopen it again

Tags: android, localization

I am trying to change app localization at runtime it working correctly but when clear app from memory and reopen it again I find that resources like strings.xml and styles.xml take the default mobile language!

Comment: So it doesn't work the second time app is opened?

Comment: yes, when I close the app and reopen it again it not working.

Comment: how are localizing your app? Are you using something like shown here?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android/35149135 How are you storing the locale? Are you using SharedPreferences?

Comment: yes, I do like this.

Comment: Okay, but are you using SharedPreference to store the locale?

Comment: yes I am storing it using SharedPreference

Comment: Okay, maybe you're missing something? I'm localizing my app doing the same, but it doesn't reset itself. I'll write my method in a few minutes, check to see if it works for you.

Comment: okay, Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my method to localize the app:

I created an abstract class like below:

```
public abstract class BaseLocalization extends AppCompatActivity {
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    Constants constants;
    String currentLocale = "en";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        constants = new Constants();
        preferences = getSharedPreferences(constants.getPreferences(), MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentLocale = preferences.getString(constants.getLocale(), "en");
        setLocale(currentLocale);

    }

    public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        Resources res = getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = myLocale;
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
}
```

After doing this, I made all the classes which extended `AppCompatActivity` extend this class. And saved the locale in `SharedPreferences`. And the locale is persisted until the app data is cleared/uninstalled.